# How to find the number of clicks on a flash banner?

Tags: nodes

There is a flash banner in a Drupal website. I want to know number of clicks on that flash banner.

**My Question**: Is there such option in Drupal (in Joomla there is one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using Google analytics and attach a click event to the banner. using a module would introduce unnecessary overheads

Answer (score 1):

You can follow WestieUK by installing the [Google Analytics-module](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) on your website or you can install the [Click-module](http://drupal.org/project/click) (Drupal < 6 only) so the admin can see exactly on which links, images,... are clicked by the users.

Or you can use the [Advertisement](http://drupal.org/project/ad) module, which will allow you to place a banner on your site and the module tracks down the traffic it's generating. And Flash is a supported format!

Comment: Did you manage to get the analytics behind the banner?